# Is there an Ubuntu-Mate version for Pinebook64?

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-mate

I bought a Pinebook Pro 64 and I want to run Ubuntu-Mate on it.  It came with Manjaro Linux, and it has an ARM processor.

[specs for Pinebook Pro](https://pine64.com/product/14%E2%80%B3-pinebook-pro-linux-laptop-ansi-us-keyboard/?v=0446c16e2e66)

Is there an Ubuntu-Mate version for Pinebook64?

Answer (score 2):

You have to download [Armbian](https://www.armbian.com/pinebook-pro) Ubuntu-based test build with MATE desktop:

- [focal, 20.04 LTS (!)](https://imola.armbian.com/dl/pinebook-pro/nightly/Armbian_21.08.0-trunk.43_Pinebook-pro_focal_current_5.10.41_mate_desktop.img.xz)
- [hirsute, 21.04](https://imola.armbian.com/dl/pinebook-pro/nightly/Armbian_21.08.0-trunk.43_Pinebook-pro_hirsute_edge_5.12.8_mate_desktop.img.xz)

Reference: [related thread](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/pinebook-pro-image/21521/11) in Ubuntu MATE community.

Images for other desktop environments can be found at the bottom of [this](https://www.armbian.com/pinebook-pro/#kernels-archive-all) webpage.

Note that Armbian is not an official Ubuntu flavor and is not supported on this site, but it is almost the same as regular Ubuntu for ARM processors, and most workarounds for Ubuntu would work there too.

Answer (score 1):

The hardware ports available for Ubuntu Mate are listed here: https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/

If there is not one (and there isn't one listed for the Pinebook currently) there's probably no image that'll work directly for the Pinebook64.

You can *attempt* to use one of the other images, however it's ill-advised as it may cause chaos on your system or brick the device.

Comment: Evidently there is no way to reply to your response.

But I thought that I had heard that Mate was supported, and that is why I got the Pinebook Pro.  As it turns out, I found this info:

Manjaro ARM

The manjaro-arm-installer script is intended to install Manjaro ARM directly to SD/eMMC cards without the need for images (including LXQT, **Mate** & CuboCore editions, as well as full disk encryption). Running on a Linux x86 computer, it can install Manjaro ARM directly to an empty eMMC using an eMMC to USB adapter. The script can also be run from SD to install an image to the eMMC.

Comment: FYI this is not a forum.  That's why you can't 'reply' to my post except to make a comment.  You're referring to Manjaro creating a MATE DE variant that works on your ARM64.  **MATE** is a desktop environment.  **Ubuntu MATE** is a variant of Ubuntu that uses the MATE desktop environment.  It is NOT manjaro linux nor does it have any relation other than the 'same desktop environment'.  There are no Ubuntu MATE images made for your hardware, so there's no support for it currently.  What Manjaro does and what the Ubuntu MATE team do are irrelevant to each other.

Comment: So, I guess what you are saying is that the user-interface is meant to be the same, but some underlying commands would be different?

Comment: @jerry the UI would be nearly identical (except maybe default themes) but underneath you will have a wide variance of differences from commands, kernel configurations, system configurations, how you get/install software, etc.  One's Manjaro, one's Ubuntu.  They're apples and oranges, the only thing they are 'sharing' is the same DE but with possibly-different default themeing.

Comment: @jerry At the core, though, you've asked if there's an Ubuntu MATE version of the images for Pinebook64, and there isn't (right now).  Maybe the MATE team will build such for the future, but Manjaro Linux is Manjaro, Ubuntu Linux is Ubuntu, they're completely different beasts and have no impact on each other.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  I wondered how Manjaro commands were so different from Ubuntu.  And I really don't want to be switching OS's all the time.  But the Mate interface, I do like.  And I'm getting used to Ubuntu also.  So your efforts are appreciated.  I am hoping to accomplish some open source development in the realm of CNC - Numerical Control Programming Language and manufacturing utilities like feedrate calculators, etc.  I think there is a huge market for people wanting to switch from Windows to Linux, but the software needs to be there for them.